# Как с помощью java получить дочерний элемент документа из alfresco?

Tags: java, alfresco, liferay

Для портала Liferay создано приложение, которое получает свойства (имя, дата, статус) документа из alfresco. У документа также есть дочерний элемент (обычно это pdf файл или картинка). Как с помощью java получить этот элемент?

Answer (score 0):

Из spring получаете nodeService, либо через serviceRegistry

```
...
private NodeService nodeService;
```

Далее, получаем дочерние элементы для нужной ноды

```
List<ChildAssociationRef> childAssocs = nodeService().getChildAssocs(nodeRef);
```